# Covert gcc arguments to CMake file

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, cmake

So I am trying to learn CMake and I want to convert the following

```
gcc "-DARCH=\"`uname -a`\"" cli_arch.c arch.c
```

to a CMakeLists.txt file.

This is what I got so far:

Running `` cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc "-DARCH=\"`uname -a`\"" .. ``

```
// CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(cli_arch)


add_executable(cli_arch cli_arch.c arch.c)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.3.11030032
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    ARCH
```

I am not understanding how to pass the arguments `` "-DARCH=\"`uname -a`\"" `` to CMake.

Comment: Do you want cmake to call uname, or do you want the result of that call passed to cmake by whomever invokes it?

Comment: I would like the result of that call to be passed into the program so cmake? Basically I have a program that just prints the arch of the compiler. So like this :

`printf("Hello, my architecture is %s\n", ARCH);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is `execute_process`.

```
execute_process(COMMAND uname -s
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE uname_output
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

add_executable(cli_arch cli_arch.c arch.c)
target_compile_definitions(cli_arch
    PRIVATE "-DARCH=\"${uname_output}\""
)
```

I had to use `uname -s` since at least on my system, `uname -a` has a # which gcc refuses to accept in a macro via the command line.

Edit, since you changed your question.  You're passing `ARCH` to cmake but not doing anything will it.  You can pass the argument along using the same `target_compile_definitions` line I have above.

```
$ cmake -DARCH2=foo .
$ make
$ ./a 
Linux
foo
```

The relevant part of the new `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
target_compile_definitions(a
    PRIVATE "-DARCH=\"${uname_output}\""
    PRIVATE "-DARCH2=\"${ARCH2}\""
)
```